# Drawing a arrow tip with text in it or a double arrow with different angles on both tips

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, arrows

[image]

I need to draw a figure as attached. Any help is appreciated. I tried a double arrow but I an unable to give different angles on both tips. Any other idea is welcome.

Comment: I think that's a `signal` shape....   So you need something like `\node[..... signal from=west to=east...]`

Comment: Welcome to TexSE by the way, and perhaps you might like add a MWE for people to start from?  It makes it easier if you give us a minimal example to show what you are trying... See [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like drawing...you can use Mathcha, a flexible tool, at the link https://www.mathcha.io/editor, to obtain your image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}       
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 169; green, 252; blue, 79 },fill opacity=1] (218.5,95) -- (316.5,95) -- (326.5,136) -- (316.5,177) -- (218.5,177) -- (228.5,136) -- cycle ;
\draw (235,126) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {Line plan};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering the question.

Comment: @AnuragGupta You're welcome :-)..all the best.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start for you.  This took a few minutes of hunting in the voluminous, and seriously comprehensive [manual](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.symbols} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[signal, fill=green!65!black, signal from=west, signal to=east] at (0,0) {Line plan}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for searching in the manual and helping me out.